# Looking for super simple but effective BUG/Feature list that users can vote

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, rating, voting

I am looking for some javascript or php code where it allows anyone to enter something in a list, and allows people to vote (1 vote per IP or cookie) or rate (not important, OK, important).

There would be two lists, one for people suggest features and also rate features up and down in the list. The other would be bugs, for people to vote up a bug they want fixed or to submit a new bug.

This would only be used by say 50 users so simplicity is wanted.

Does anyone have a basic script or example of this? I am need of a way to track what my users want in the application, and also give them a way to submit stuff they want fixed.

An idea that inspired this is this page: http://kryogenix.org/bugs/sorttable/ 
seems manually done, not automated though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try http://uservoice.com/

It's not a bug tracker in the classical sense, but it allows users to add suggestions and have other users vote on them (just like you asked for). One list would be free. If you need multiple list you have to pay a fee, but they give discounts for non-profits.

Comment: @Phantom http://uservoice.com/plans says "Our free plan includes 1 forum, custom logo, API and widgets"

Comment: Apologies - was hidden on first (and second) glance !